# Select statement in Hypertable in Java

Tags: java, select, hypertable

I am using hypertable in java program (I know it should be used in C++).

I want to use SELECT sql query in java program. But I am unable to select. The Result is coming as `null`.

Please advice whether we can use SQL hypertable statement in Java program. If yes, please give some sample code.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide your own problematic code. We do not read minds here.

Answer (score 1):

download the hypertable sources and unpack them, then look into this directory:

```
hypertable/src/Java/ThriftClient/org/hypertable/thrift
```

it has a file called `BasicClientTest.java` which does a `select` query.

bye
Christoph